# How to increment posts within a specific category for every 6 posts of all categories

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, increment, posts

I am successfully returning a post from the 'CTA' category every 6 posts on the page. However every time the loop is run I get stuck with the first post in the array instead of the incremental progression of all the CTA posts.

I've tried returning the posts by RAND order and that worked better but did have repeats. I don't seem to be able to get the count set for the CTA category after already setting a counter for every six posts.

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) {  ?>

    <?php while ($query->have_posts()) {

         if( $query -> post_count > 0 ) {

                 $postnum = 0;

         foreach( $query -> posts as $post ) {

                  $postnum++;

                  if( $postnum%5 == 0 ) {

                    $args = array( 'cat' => 1824, 'posts_per_page' => 1, );
                    query_posts( $args );
                    $current_post = 0;
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        $current_post++;

                        echo "CTA Card Specific Info";
                    endwhile;

                }

                $query->the_post();


            ?>
```

Comment: What do you really want to achieve here?

Comment: I want to display posts from all categories on a page and every 6 of those posts needs to be a from one specific category. I have that working but it's showing the same post from that category on every sixth post instead of incrementing through that specific category.